# Image classifier only predicting 2 out of 6 classes and val accuracy is high, what is happening?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, image-augmentation

I'm new to machine learning and I'm working on a dataset with 14k pictures of sea, forest, glaciers, streets, buildings and mountains (6 classes). I have been training my model with it and achieved a val acc of 91% but for some reason it is biased, when I try to predict new images with my inference code the only classes chosen are glaciers and sea. Here is the [Github](https://github.com/IguanaAncestral/Intel-) with the model creation code and the inference code.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range= 20,  # Rotate the augmented image by 20 degrees
zoom_range=0.3,  # Zoom by 20% more or less
horizontal_flip=True,  # Allow for horizontal flips of augmented images
vertical_flip=True,  # Allow for vertical flips of augmented images
brightness_range=[0.6, 1.2],  # Lighter and darker images 
fill_mode='nearest', 
preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

img_data_iterator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
# Where to take the data from, the classes are the sub folder names
'../Q2B/archive/seg_train/seg_train/',
class_mode="categorical",  # classes are in 2D one hot encoded way 
shuffle=True,  # shuffle the data, default is true but just to point it out
batch_size=32,
target_size=(150, 150),  # This size is the default of mobilenet NN)

validation_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
preprocessing_function=preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(
'../Q2B/archive/seg_test/seg_test/',
class_mode="categorical",
shuffle=True,
batch_size=32,
target_size=(150, 150),)
```

My guess is that it is related to the way I pre-processed the data.

Answer (score 0):

can you post more of your code.
Change the class_mode to 'categorical' for the train and test generators
Change the final dense layer from 1 to 2 so this will return scores/probabilities for both classes. So when you use argmax, it will return the index position of the top score indicating which class it has predicted.

Comment: are you able to open the github code? note sure if the link works for everybody. The class_mode is set to categorical in both generators and the final dense layer is set to 6 since I have 6 classes, but when I run the inference code, which is also in github, it only predicts two classes.